# Specifically filling new matrix with elements from two different matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am fairly new to matlab and am struggling to write code to fill a matrix

I have two matrices I1 and I2 (both have dimensions 255x255)
I would like to write code to create a new matrix that has the element values from I1 in, unless the element equals 255- in which case I would like to use the element from the same coordinate from I2 instead.

I hope this makes sense! 
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/):

```
result = I1;
ind = result==255; %// logical index
result(ind) = I2(ind);
```

Or using a mask:

```
ind = I1==255; %// logical index, used as a mask
result = ~ind.*I1 + ind.*I2;
```